# How to build a WordPress plugin out of this?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have build the following application: http://codecanyon.net/item/secure-login-system/1379963, and I got some requests for a WordPress version of it. My knowledge of WordPress is very little, so I'm asking here where should I start learning how to build a plugin or what should I do and how ?

I'm quite experienced with PHP and client side coding ( jQuery, JavaScript, ... ), but I never worked with WordPress. So how should I proceed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of info at wordpress.org:  http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_Resources  and http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API